# Idéia para biblioteca de limpeza e tratamento de dados

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, segurança, sql-injection

Eu preciso fazer um biblioteca para tratamento de dados, para que eu possa usá-la antes de chamar funções como: Cadastrar, Alterar, Excluir e etc...

Estou usando PDO para comunicação com o banco de dados mysql, e o próprio método já tem algumas medidas de segurança para evitar sql injection, mas gostaria de uma segurança a mais.

Andei pesquisando e não achei nada melhor do que os filter sanitize que a própria linguagem php oferece, mas creio que tenha formas melhores e mais completas de se usar esses recursos.

Segue a função que fiz:

```
function limpeza($dados) {
    foreach ($dados as $key => $valor) {
        if (is_numeric($valor)) {
            $dados[$key] = filter_var($dados[$key], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        } else {
            $dados[$key] = filter_var(utf8_decode($dados[$key]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }
    }
    return $dados;
}
```

A minha ideia é pegar por exemplo o array com o POST do formulário e passar direto para a função, e que ela me retorne um array limpo e livre de por exemplo tags html,php ou outros scripts maliciosos. Do jeito que está, a função limpa realmente todas as tags e scripts maliciosos e me retorna o array limpo. Mas sinto que tem formas muito melhores de se fazer, e não achei muito conteúdo na internet sobre isso.

Comment: E diferença entre `int` e `float` ? Parece me mais seguro partir de um [`gettype`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) em vez de um `is_numeric`. E até pode receber um segundo array opcional como parâmetro com o filtro a aplicar a cada campo, para poder em alguns casos aplicar `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` por exemplo

Comment: Verifique a classe https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP, fácil de extender, e simples de usar.

Comment: De uma olhada na [SafeMySQL](https://phpdelusions.net/safemysql). É um wrapper do mysqli para resolver os problemas de segurança, leitura, implementação e repetição que o codigo em sida mysqli pode proporcionar. Ele é desenvolvido/mantido por um usuário do SO.